# Kafka-connect. Add environment variable to custom converter config

Tags: apache-kafka, environment-variables, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using `kafka-connect-elasticsearch` with a custom converter, which extents standard `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`.

In my custom converter I need to access an environment variable.
Let's assume, I need to append to every message the name of the cluster, which is written to environment variable `CLUSTER`.

How can I access my environment variable in the converter?
Maybe read it at converter configuration phase (`configure(Map<String, ?> configs)` methond)?
How can I forward `CLUSTER` env variable value to this `configs` map?

Comment: Changing variables would require a JVM restart. Why not use the `InsertField` SMT? https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it in that map.

You would need to use `System.getenv("CLUSTER")`